# Code runs fine in .html, but not in blogspot.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blogger, blogspot

I’m trying to get a value from a JSONP address and show it in a new line of text. The script runs fine in .html (saving to .html and opening in desktop), but it doesn’t work when posting to a blog (blogspot.com).

I’ve already seen an answer here based on functions that make the code load only after the document has finished loading, but my code already has that function, and it doesn’t work anyway.

Also, I know blogspot.com allows javascript and jquery from my own experience.

Doesn’t it allow ajax requests? I haven’t seen such a statement on the web.

Any help is appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button#butt").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("http://api.sidra.ibge.gov.br/values/t/1419/n1/all/h/n/v/69/p/last%201?formato=json", function(data) {
        var json = data, obj = JSON.parse(json);
        $("#div1").text(obj[0].V);
    });
  });
});
</script>

<div id='div1'></div>
<button id="butt">Show value</button>
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Tried to run it on the console of a blogspot page, and it complains that the url is not HTTPs, therefore, it does not allow the request. Also, looks like they do not accept cross-domain request.

Comment: @FelipeGonçalvesMarques It worked! My blog was configured to be redirected to _https_, therefore it would block any _non-https_ content. I turned this off (Blogger > Dashboard > Settings > Basic > HTTPS) and the script now runs smoothly. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Felipe Gonçalves Marques in the comments above, one of the URLs wasn't HTTPs, which made it incompatible with the webpage, since it uses the HTTPs protocol by default. I fixed it by deselecting the automatic HTTPs redirection in Blogger's settings.